# mounting a raw disk in a backup

Tags: android, backup, system

I trying to get **all** data from my android phone. I got alot of files named: ".backup".

step 1:

```
cat userdata_20200107_174037.backup userdata_20200107_174037.backup1 userdata_20200107_174037.backup2 userdata_20200107_174037.backup3 userdata_20200107_174037.backup4 userdata_20200107_174037.backup5 userdata_20200107_174037.backup6 userdata_20200107_174037.backup7 userdata_20200107_174037.backup8 userdata_20200107_174037.backup9 userdata_20200107_174037.backup10 userdata_20200107_174037.backup11 userdata_20200107_174037.backup12 userdata_20200107_174037.backup13 > userdata.img
```

step 2 if this not works goto step3:

```
dd if=userdata.img bs=512 skip=1 | gunzip -c | tar xv
```

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: This does not look like a tar
>   archive tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

step 3:

```
simg2img userdata.img userdata_raw.img
```

> Invalid sparse file format at header magi Failed to read sparse file

step 4:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw userdata.img /media/phone/
```

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop8,
>   missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases
>   useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

i Follow the stack overflow here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/how-to-extract-backup-files-created-by-android-stock-recovery

Is there a easy way to backup all data in android ? and how can i do it? hole data include system??

Note:

> then i run (file userdata.img) it's **data** file
>
> and not **Android sparse image** (file)

Comment: Have you ever tried adb backup?

Comment: Yes i have try that.

Comment: the problem is userdata_20200107_174037.backup can be in 6 different formats, (one or all parts) with or without 512 bytes header checksum, and in your case encrypted